# Prime Number test in java

Tags: java

```
public static boolean isPrime(int number)
{
  boolean result = true;

  if (number == 0)
  {
     result = false;
  }

  for (int i=2; i < number/2; i++)
  {
     if (number % i == 0)
     {
        result = false;
     }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Any ideas why when int number = 4, the result returns as true? What can I do to fix this? I am happy with the code I have but why does 4 return as true?

Comment: Can't you just do it on pen and paper? Take `number = 4`. Then `i = 2`. Then `number % i = ...`.

Comment: if `number` is 4, how many times does the for-loop execute?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that is exactly what does not happen.

Comment: 1. Do not set default value of `result` as `true`. For `4` the for loop will not execute so you are returning the default value of `result` which is `true`

Comment: @arunmoezhi if you don't set the default value to `true`, no number will ever be reported as prime.

Comment: @Sneftel: exactly. But it is a good programming practice to set it to false and modify the logic according to it. It it better to give red lights at all corners rather than giving green lights to all corners.

Comment: @arunmoezhi That doesn't make any sense. Primality testing (as implemented here) is based on the failure to find integer factors, and that for-loop is iterating over possible integer factors.

Comment: `as implemented here`. I suggested to change the implementation

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i=2; i < number/2; i++)
```

If you enter `4` here, it will never enter the loop because

```
2 < 4 / 2
```

never equates to `true` (2 is not smaller than 2).

Instead, use `<=`.

Comment: Pretty sure you can do `(int)Math.sqrt(number)` instead of `number/2` : )

Answer (score 2):

Effective way how to do this method is :
(sorry for duplication, but after some time, someone can find this topic and not previous one)

```
public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
    //Everything less or equal 1 is not prime number
    if (number <= 1) {
        return false;
    }

    //2 is very special case, so I check it separately
    if (number == 2) {
        return true;
    }

    //This will help me rid off all even numbers
    if (number % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }


    //It is important to count the sqrt before using it in for-loop condition.
    //If you use it in for-loop condition, it will be counted every single iteration.
    int square = (int) Math.sqrt(number);

    //I already checked %2, so now I need to check only odd numbers
    for (int i = 3; i <= square; i += 2) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            //If I find one number, I do not have to continue
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Or even add an extra check for 3 as factor and use then `for (int i = 5, d=2; i <= square; i += d, d=6-d) {` to only check for factors that are neither divisible by 2 nor by 3. This is the [2-3-wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization). Also in use are 2-3-5 and 2-3-5-7 wheels.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop never executes when `number = 4`. This is because:

```
for (int i=2; i < number/2; i++)
```

Executes when `i == 2` and `i < 2`. That will never happen if `number == 4`, because then it'll be `i < 4 / 2` which is `i < 2`. To solve this, remove the `/2` or do something else... not quite sure what you're going for there.

Answer (score 1):

When number==4 the boolean condition of the first `if` is false and the first evaluation of the `for` condition is also false. So the result is the value you used to initialize result (true).

Answer (score 1):

Also, you might want to return the result instead of storing it in a variable because the code will continue to execute after the first conditional... So here is the working solution:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
  if (number <= 1) { /* Since 1 isn't technically a prime number */
     return false;
  }

  for (int i=2; i <= number/2; i++) {
     if (number % i == 0) {
       return false;
     }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: @libik: why doesn't it?

Comment: 1 is not prime, so <= 1 will return false :)

Answer (score 0):

Better and faster version of your code:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
        if (number <= 1) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i=2; i*i <= number; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
    if (number < 2) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i=2; i <= (int)Math.sqrt(number); i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```